# Compile the java code by using the following command as mentioned below

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was doing WordCount using Ubuntu Shell, when I was Compile the java code by using the following command as mentioned below

```
javac -classpath ${HADOOP_CLASSPATH} -d
‘/home/abdullah/Desktop/WordCountTutorial/tutorial_classes’
‘/home/abdullah/Desktop/WordCountTutorial/WordCount.java’
```

I got the error below

```
javac invalid flag:‘/home/abdullah/Desktop/WordCountTutorial/tutorial_classes’
‘/home/abdullah/Desktop/WordCountTutorial/WordCount.java’
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: Those look like smart quotes in your javac command. It won't like that.

Answer (score 0):

I can observe following issues:

1. Quotes: Don't give quotes. -d expects a directory path.
2. direct directory path : should be changed with a java file path or use `**/*.java` e.g. `/home/abdullah/Desktop/WordCountTutorial/tutorial_classes/*.java`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have the same problem